# Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3"

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I cannot figure out why the error below is being thrown. I have followed babel's official migration guide to 7, all of my babel dependencies are the 7 equivalents and I get this error:

```
Error: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3". If 
you are sure you have a compatible version of @babel/core, it is likely that something in your build process is loading the wrong version. 
Inspect the stack trace of this error to look for the first entry that doesn't mention "@babel/core" or "babel-core" to see what is calling 
Babel.
at throwVersionError (/code/node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/lib/index.js:65:11)
at Object.assertVersion (/code/node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/lib/index.js:13:11)
at _default (/code/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread/lib/index.js:41:7)
at /code/node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/lib/index.js:19:12
at Function.memoisePluginContainer (/code/node_modules/babel-register/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:113:13)
at Function.normalisePlugin (/code/node_modules/babel-register/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:146:32)
at /code/node_modules/babel-register/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:184:30
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at Function.normalisePlugins (/code/node_modules/babel-register/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:158:20)
at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/code/node_modules/babel-register/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:234:36)
at OptionManager.init (/code/node_modules/babel-register/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:368:12)
at compile (/code/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:103:45)
at loader (/code/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:14)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/code/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/code/src/backend/test/test.js:66:3)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Module._compile (/code/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:83:24)
at Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Object.newLoader (/code/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:88:7)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at /code/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:220:27
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Mocha.loadFiles (/code/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:217:14)
at Mocha.run (/code/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:469:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (/code/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:404:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

While the error says to look for non babel-core or @babel/core entries, there are lots of them and I guess the most obvious one is the `pirates` package which itself is a dependency of `babel-register`?!?

My dependencies:

```
...
"@babel/cli": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-do-expressions": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-logical-assignment-operators": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/node": "^7.0.0",
...
```

and am running mocha with the `--compilers js:@babel/register` switch.

Comment: You may be loading `@babel/register`, but something is clearly loading `babel-register` so you'd have to figure out what that something is.

Comment: By something you mean one of the other dependencies or a dependency of those dependencies?

Comment: Yeah I'd search through your `node_modules` to see what references `babel-register` and double-check your own build scripts and application code.

Comment: it could be /code/src/backend/test/test.js:66 ?